# How to make the text string inside the CSS content property selectable?

Tags: html, css, web

The text that displayed using CSS content property is unselectable. Why ?

EXample :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
p:before
{
content:"My name is ";
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<p> Donald</p>


</body>
</html>
```

The output of the above code is :

> My name is Donald

Now here the problem is the text **My name is**  from  `content:"My name is ";` is unselectable .

How to make it selectable.

Comment: :after and :before pseudo-elements are NOT part of the DOM.